# ES 1.5 Delete By Query API not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using an old version on ElasticSearch - 1.5.

Problem: I need to delete a lot of documents, like few hundred thousands up to few millions. I have all the info about the records, including it's `_id`s - so array of `_id`s is what I want to use.

Scale problem: I had this deletion in the loop before, but ES is inconsistent when performing a lot of subsequent operations in a high speed. Thus I decided to look for a bulk delete.

I am trying to make use of [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/docs-delete-by-query.html).

Docs states:

> ```
> curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_query' -d '{
>     "query" : {
>         "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
>     }
> }
> '
> ```

What I'm doing:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/logs/_query' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "terms" : { "_id" : ["AVTD6fhLAn35BG25xbZz", "AVTD6fhLAn35BG25xbaC"] }
  }
}
'
```

The response is:

```
{
  "found":false,
  "_index":"my_index",
  "_type":"logs",
  "_id":"_query",
  "_version":1,
  "_shards":{"total":2, "successful":1, "failed":0}
}
```

And it does not remove any of documents. How do I make it work and actually delete these records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the delete_by_query API in elasticsearch 1.5. Seems to me that elasticsearch is unable to understand your query as it is looking for `"_id": "_query"` (as evident from the response you posted).

What you can do is, use the Bulk API as documented here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/docs-bulk.html

As in the example in the doc page, you can do:

```
curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests; echo
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
...
```

You need to make a file by any name ("requests" here) and add individual delete requests, each separated by a newline character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! yea, I see that it;s confused, but it makes me confused, because I do exactly what docs say... I believe it's an option but would still like to get try everything with delete by query.

Comment: I don't know about elasticsearch 1.5, but in 2.x delete_by_query worked only on installing the delete_by_query plugin. Couldn't find anything like that about 1.5 though. 
Any reason why you want to do it with delete_by_query only?

Comment: I believe creating a file of 1mil lines is quite heavy/not-so-cheap operation :)

Comment: But, do you plan on writing all the 1 million Ids in the array in delete_by_query?

Comment: yep, it's a single request and ES can handle it

Comment: I don't see then, what the problem is with bulk. Are you using an elasticsearch client(PHP/python/Java library) to delete the docs or are you running a simple curl request (on sense or terminal)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160195/discussion-between-archit-saxena-and-andrey-deineko).